# Is there a way to connect an azure-function to a VPN?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, vpn

Apologies in advance for any incorrect terminology as I'm just starting out with learning about networking...

I am trying to connect my azure-function to a VPN. I am able to connect my laptop to this VPN connection with a server address (e.g. 185.142.249.12), account name, password, shared-secret, and group name. I am then able to run my python function code locally just fine (the code sends a request to an API that is only available in the VPN).

However when I deploy my azure-function I am unable to establish a connection with the VPN. There seems to be very little documentation on the matter, however I did follow this tutorial to no avail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal

I also tried to establish a VPN-connection with python code but was also unsuccessful.

What would be the correct approach to this problem? Is it even possible to connect an azure-function to a VPN? Or is it possible to start a VPN connection in python code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should configure your function app to use VNet `subnets` and also configure your VPN firewall to _allow_ inbound connections from the Azure IP range. Consumption plan does not support this, you must use other tiers - refer this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options?tabs=azure-cli), and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet)

Comment: Do you want to make Function App connectivity to on-premise resources through VPN or access Function App from local network through VPN?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use vnet integration on your function app.
See this documentation on how to set it up. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options?tabs=azure-cli#virtual-network-integration
Make sure all outbound traffic from the function app goes through the dedicated subnet by setting VNET_ROUTE_ALL as seen here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-vnet-integration-routing

Once you're this far, you'll need to enable the vpn gateway. You already found the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal) for that process.

As suggested in the comments, make sure your firewalls are allowing access.

At this point, the function app should be able to access IPs in your on-prem network. If you need DNS resolution, then you'll have to follow [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#name-resolution-that-uses-your-own-dns-server) on how to setup a custom DNS server for the Azure VNET.